# Android WorkManager "Constraints may not be met for some devices"

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have periodic work with

```
.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
.setRequiresCharging(true)
.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
```

Lint says that some Android devices can't be IDLE and CHARGING in the same time.
Is there any way to understand if current device can meet such Worker constraints or not?

I have some ideas like remove IDLE constraint and listen screen on/off or remove CHARGING and check it on Job start but I don't like it.

Comment: Were you able to find any more about this? I'm working on the exact same issue. Thanks!

Comment: No updated here from my side. If you discover any solutions, please share. Thanks!